# Recording frequency of taps on screen while app is in background

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Let's say I have an app A and an app B. App A runs and does calculations in the background and I have an app B running on the main thread. While app B runs on main thread I tap on screen 120 times, is there a way for an app A record screen taps even though it was running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via an overlay. Create a dummy view something like 1 pixel and place it somewhere out the way in one of the corners. Then set up a touch event listener ( onTouch ) make sure it returns false though or the actual place you touch wont register the event.

Comment: Do I set up a touch event listener on that 1px view?